If $f'$ is periodic , are $f , f'$ uniformly continuous?
$f: ℝ \rightarrow ℝ $ is such that $f'$ exist and $f'$ is periodic. Are $f ,f'$ uniformly continuous ?
Attempt :- I was thinking along a counter example . What if $f'(x)=\tan x$ but then $f(x)=\ln (|sec x|) $ but then it's not becoming continuous at some points .
Is the result actually true? I certainly know some results using existence of $\lim_{x\rightarrow c} f'(x)  $ and if the right hand and left hand limit of $f'(x)$ at $x=c$ are not equal , then $f$ is not differentiable at $c$
But  these limits may not exist , right ?
Any hints. Thanks .

Take $f'(x)=x$ on $[0,1)$ and prolonged over $\mathbb R$ by $1-$ periodicty... $f'$ is even not continuous.

@Surb   Ok then $f(x)=x^2 / 2 , x \in [0 , 1)$. extended over $\mathbb{R}$  . But then $f$ is not continuous at integers ?

Actually, existence of derivative at every point makes this question quite non-trivial. There are no easy counter-examples.

@geetha290krm is right.  There is a function $f$ where $f'$ exists everywhere but $f'$ is not continuous.  Can it be made periodic?

Take $f(x):=x^2\sin(\frac{\text{sign}(x)}{x})$. Take any minimum or maximum point $p\neq 0$ of $f$.
Now define $g$ as the periodic extension of $f|_{[-p,p]}$, which is well defined since $f$ is symmetric. Its derivative exists everywhere since $f$ is everywhere differentiable, and $\lim_{h\downarrow -p}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} =\lim_{h\uparrow p}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=0$.
But since $f'$ isn't continuous, neither is $g'$.

You can easily prove that if Df is continuous then f and Df are uniformally continuous, so think about taking a non continuous periodic function...

A non-continuous periodic function need not be a  derivative.
